# Filter GeoPandas dataframe within specific long/lat range?

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a bird migration dataset which shows a few birds and their location according to date. But there are points across several countries. I only want to display one country and those data points. How would I do that? I have seen similar posts that filter by country, but I only have the longitude and latitude of each point. There are no country names in this dataset. I don't want to filter the dataset before importing it (that would be easy, sure), because it should be a Python (programmatic) solution. I don't see any function with geopandas that will allow me to specify a range of long/lat, unless I missed something.

Original dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/saikrishna20/bird-tracking

Here's what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import contextily as ctx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

# Create a new map with limits on long/lat for France
bird_df = pd.read_csv('bird_tracking.csv')

# Designate the right coordinate system (maps can be drawn differently)
crs = 'EPSG:4326'

# Takes the lat and long and puts into list of single points (shapefly)
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['longitude'], df['latitude'])]

# Create GeoPandas dataframe (adds our bird tracking data frame)
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(bird_df, crs = crs, geometry = geometry)

# create figure and map axes, assign to subplot (matplotlib)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))

# specify France map coordinates and add more formatting
geo_df.to_crs('EPSG:3857').plot(column='bird_name', linewidth=2, ax=ax, alpha=0.5, legend=True, markersize=10)

ctx.add_basemap(map, source=ctx.providers.CartoDB.Positron)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looks like pandas has a function that you can create a range of values. You use the query() function and set your condition as parameters, like this example:

```
df = df.query('5 < column_name < 15')
```

Here's my full working code:

```
# Create a new map with limits on long/lat for France
bird_df = pd.read_csv('bird_tracking.csv')

# Filter the dataset for France latitude and longitude range
bird_df = bird_df.query('-5 < longitude < 2')
bird_df = bird_df.query('45 < latitude < 50')

# Designate the right coordinate system (maps can be drawn differently)
crs = 'EPSG:4326'

# Takes the lat and long from our bird sightings, puts into list of single points (shapefly)
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(bird_df['longitude'], bird_df['latitude'])]

# Create GeoPandas dataframe (adds our bird tracking data frame)
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(bird_df, crs = crs, geometry = geometry)

# create figure and map axes, assign to subplot (matplotlib)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))

# specify France map coordinates and add more formatting
map_france = geo_df.to_crs('EPSG:3857').plot(column='bird_name', linewidth=2, ax=ax, alpha=0.5, legend=True, markersize=10)
ctx.add_basemap(map_france, source=ctx.providers.CartoDB.Positron)

# add title to map
plt.title('Bird Sightings in France', fontsize=15)
```

[image: Bird sightings in France]